# Promote a piece to queen by moving back aside of king?

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion

[image: pawn promotion]

As I was trying out different chess applications I received a hint from the Lucas Chess virtual tutor, showing me I had a better option:
Move piece C2 to C1. When I did that, the piece promoted to queen.
I've tried this on chess.com with the same result.
What (strange) rule is this, and where can I learn more about promotions?

EDIT:
Or, maybe this got triggered by the fact I had a crashed play, and had set-up the board manual, making a mistake by flipping the board so the computer thinks I'm already on the other side.
That must be it, right? :)

Comment: Yes, your edit must be right.

Comment: Yep. You can see the "1" on the bottom row and the "8" on the top row, which indicates the board is flipped from what Black usually sees.

Comment: Thx, you can imagina as I don't play regulary how weird this game was. Case solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a crashed play, and set-up the board manualy.
As I was playing black, I mistakenly flipped the board.
Thereby the computer thought I'm already on the other side.